# com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallException: Split Install Error(-7)

Tags: java, android

> Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
> Dynamic Module addOnFailureListener -> com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallException: Split Install Error(-7): Download not permitted under current device circumstances (e.g. in background). (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/model/SplitInstallErrorCode.html#ACCESS_DENIED) at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.zzbb.zzl(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:4) at com.google.android.play.core.internal.zzcb.zza(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:16) at com.google.android.play.core.internal.zzl.onTransact(com.google.android.play:core@@1.10.3:3) at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)

my code

```
public class DynamicFeatureModule {

    private List<String > modules;
    private DynamicHandler dynamicHandler;
    private Activity context;

    /**
     * Constructor untuk menginstall dan mengambil module dengan fungsi BULK
     */
    public DynamicFeatureModule(Activity context, DynamicHandler dynamicHandler) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dynamicHandler = dynamicHandler;
        modules = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Fungsi untuk menambah module yang akan di install dan di ambil
     * @param moduleName nama module
     * @return this
     */
    public DynamicFeatureModule addModule(String moduleName) {
        modules.add(moduleName);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Method untuk memulai proses install module-module yang sebelumnya sudah ditambah (addModule) secara BULK
     */
    public void start() {
        SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(context);
        Set<String> installedModules = splitInstallManager.getInstalledModules();

        Stack<String> stackModule = new Stack<>();
        for (String moduleName : modules) {
            if (installedModules.contains(moduleName)) {
                dynamicHandler.onInstalled(moduleName);
            } else {
                stackModule.push(moduleName);
            }
        }

        if (stackModule.empty()) {
            dynamicHandler.onFinished();
        } else {
            stackInstall(stackModule, splitInstallManager);
        }
    }

    private void stackInstall(Stack<String> stack, SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager) {
        if (!stack.empty()) {
            final int[] session = new int[1];
            String moduleName = stack.pop();
            SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder().addModule(moduleName).build();

            SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener listener = state -> {
                if (state.sessionId() == session[0]) {
                    switch (state.status()) {
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING:
                            dynamicHandler.onInstalling(moduleName);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING:
                            dynamicHandler.onDownloading(moduleName);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED:
                            dynamicHandler.onInstalled(moduleName);

                            if (stack.empty()) {
                                dynamicHandler.onFinished();
                            } else {
                                stackInstall(stack, splitInstallManager);
                            }

                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADED:
                            dynamicHandler.onDownloaded(moduleName);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED:
                            checkErrorState(state.errorCode(), splitInstallManager, moduleName, true);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELED:
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELING:
                            splitInstallManager.cancelInstall(session[0]);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION:
                            try {
                                splitInstallManager.startConfirmationDialogForResult(state, context, 0);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                dynamicHandler.onFailed(e.getMessage(), moduleName);

                                StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
                                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
                                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module startConfirmationDialogForResult -> " + stackTrace.toString()));
                            }

                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.PENDING:
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.UNKNOWN:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            splitInstallManager.registerListener(listener);
            splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(sessionId -> session[0] = sessionId)
                    .addOnFailureListener( e -> {
                        checkErrorState(((SplitInstallException) e).getErrorCode(), splitInstallManager, moduleName, true);

                        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module addOnFailureListener -> " + stackTrace.toString()));
                    });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fungsi untuk Download dan Install Dynamic Module (On-Demand)
     * @param context Acitvity yang menjalankan
     * @param moduleName Nama module yang ingin di download dan install
     * @param dynamicHandler listener yang mengatur hasil
     */
    public DynamicFeatureModule(Context context, String moduleName, DynamicHandler dynamicHandler) {
        SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(context);

        Set<String> installedModules = splitInstallManager.getInstalledModules();
        if (installedModules.contains(moduleName)) {
            dynamicHandler.onInstalled();
        } else {
            final int[] session = new int[1];
            SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder().addModule(moduleName).build();

            SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener listener = state -> {
                if (state.sessionId() == session[0]) {
                    switch (state.status()) {
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING:
                            dynamicHandler.onInstalling();
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING:
                            dynamicHandler.onDownloading();
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED:
                            dynamicHandler.onInstalled();
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADED:
                            dynamicHandler.onDownloaded();
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED:
                            checkErrorState(state.errorCode(), splitInstallManager, moduleName, false);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELED:
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELING:
                            splitInstallManager.cancelInstall(session[0]);
                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION:
                            try {
                                splitInstallManager.startConfirmationDialogForResult(state, this.context, 0);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                dynamicHandler.onFailed(e.getMessage(), moduleName);

                                StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
                                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
                                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module startConfirmationDialogForResult -> " + stackTrace.toString()));
                            }

                            break;
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.PENDING:
                        case SplitInstallSessionStatus.UNKNOWN:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            splitInstallManager.registerListener(listener);
            splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(sessionId -> session[0] = sessionId)
                    .addOnFailureListener( e -> {
                        checkErrorState(((SplitInstallException) e).getErrorCode(), splitInstallManager, moduleName, false);

                        StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module addOnFailureListener -> " + stackTrace.toString()));
                    });
        }
    }

    private void checkErrorState(int errorCode, SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager, String moduleName, boolean stack) {
        if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.ACTIVE_SESSIONS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
            checkForActiveDownloads(splitInstallManager, moduleName);
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.ACTIVE_SESSIONS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.NETWORK_ERROR) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Masalah KONEKSI dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Masalah KONEKSI dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.NETWORK_ERROR"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.MODULE_UNAVAILABLE) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Module tidak tersedia dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Module tidak tersedia dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.MODULE_UNAVAILABLE"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.INVALID_REQUEST) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Invalid Request dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Invalid Request dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.INVALID_REQUEST"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_FOUND) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Sesi tidak ditemukan dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Sesi tidak ditemukan dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_FOUND"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.API_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("API tidak tersedia dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("API tidak tersedia dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.API_NOT_AVAILABLE"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.ACCESS_DENIED) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Akses ditolak dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Akses ditolak dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.ACCESS_DENIED"));

        } else if (errorCode == SplitInstallErrorCode.INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION) {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Sesi tidak cocok dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Sesi tidak cocok dalam memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> SplitInstallErrorCode.INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_EXISTING_SESSION"));

        } else {
            if (stack) {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Gagal memasang fitur " + moduleName, moduleName);
            } else {
                dynamicHandler.onFailed("Gagal memasang fitur " + moduleName);
            }

            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("Dynamic Module errorCode (" + moduleName + ") : " + errorCode + " -> UNKNOWN ERROR"));
        }
    }

    private void checkForActiveDownloads(SplitInstallManager splitInstallManager, String moduleName) {
        splitInstallManager
            .getSessionStates()
            .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (SplitInstallSessionState state : task.getResult()) {
                        if (state.status() == SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING) {
                            splitInstallManager.deferredInstall(Collections.singletonList(moduleName));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

```
public class DynamicHandler {

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sedang Mengunduh Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onDownloading() {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sedang Memasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onInstalling() {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sudah terpasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onInstalled() {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sudah berhasil mengunduh Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onDownloaded() {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika gagal mengunduh atau memasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onFailed(String exception) {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sedang Mengunduh Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onDownloading(String moduleName) {

    }


    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sedang Memasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onInstalling(String moduleName) {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sudah terpasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onInstalled(String moduleName) {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika sudah berhasil mengunduh Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onDownloaded(String moduleName) {

    }

    /**
     * Akan menjalankan method ini jika gagal mengunduh atau memasang Dynamic Module
     */
    public void onFailed(String exception, String moduleName) {

    }

    public void onFinished() {

    }
}
```

```
DynamicFeatureModule dynamicFeatureModule = new DynamicFeatureModule(LoginActivity.this, new DynamicHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloading(String moduleName) {
                        dismissDialog();

                        switch (moduleName) {
                            case "performance":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur performa");
                                break;
                            case "monitor":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur monitor");
                                break;
                            case "history":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur history");
                                break;
                            case "dashboardoperator":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur Dashboard Operator");
                                break;
                            case "dashboardppl":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur Dashboard PPL");
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInstalling(String moduleName) {
                        dismissDialog();

                        switch (moduleName) {
                            case "performance":
                                showDialog("Memasang fitur performa");
                                break;
                            case "monitor":
                                showDialog("Memasang fitur monitor");
                                break;
                            case "history":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur history");
                                break;
                            case "dashboardoperator":
                                showDialog("Mengunduh fitur Dashboard Operator");
                                break;
                            case "dashboardppl":
                                showDialog("Memasang fitur Dashboard PPL");
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailed(String exception, String moduleName) {
                        dismissDialog();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, exception, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInstalled(String moduleName) {
                        try {
                            switch (moduleName) {
                                case "performance":
                                    InstanceVar.performFragment = (Fragment) Class.forName("id.pitik.mobile.performance.ui.fragment.PerformFragment").newInstance();
                                    break;
                                case "monitor":
                                    InstanceVar.monitorFragment = (Fragment) Class.forName("id.pitik.mobile.monitor.ui.fragment.MonitorFragment").newInstance();

                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("endpointLatestCondition", "latestHistorical");
                                    bundle.putString("endpointTemperature", "realTime");
                                    bundle.putString("endpointHumidity", "realTime");
                                    bundle.putString("endpointHeatStress", "realTime");
                                    bundle.putString("endpointWindSpeed", "realTime");
                                    bundle.putString("endpointLights", "realTime");
                                    InstanceVar.monitorFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                    break;
                                case "history":
                                    InstanceVar.historyFragment = (Fragment) Class.forName("id.pitik.mobile.history.ui.fragment.HistoryFragment").newInstance();
                                    break;
                                case "dashboardoperator":
                                    InstanceVar.homeOperatorFragment = (Fragment) Class.forName("id.pitik.mobile.dashboardoperator.ui.fragment.HomeFragment").newInstance();
                                    break;
                                case "dashboardppl":
                                    InstanceVar.homePplFragment = (Fragment) Class.forName("id.pitik.mobile.dashboardppl.ui.fragment.HomePplFragment").newInstance();
                                    break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            dismissDialog();
                            runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, moduleName + " Feature Failed..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinished() {
                        dismissDialog();
                        launch(body.getData(), bodyProfile.getData());
                    }
                });

                if (bodyProfile.getData().getShowPerformance()) {
                    dynamicFeatureModule.addModule("performance");
                }

                if (bodyProfile.getData().getShowMonitoring()) {
                    dynamicFeatureModule.addModule("monitor");
                }

                if (bodyProfile.getData().getShowHistory()) {
                    dynamicFeatureModule.addModule("history");
                }

                if (bodyProfile.getData().getUserType().equals("ppl") || bodyProfile.getData().getUserType().equals("mitra manager")|| bodyProfile.getData().getUserType().equals("area manager")|| bodyProfile.getData().getUserType().equals("pembantu umum")) {
                    dynamicFeatureModule.addModule("dashboardppl");
                } else {
                    dynamicFeatureModule.addModule("dashboardoperator");
                }

                dynamicFeatureModule.start();
```

i got such problem while using dynamic feature.

In this problem it says that my application is in the background, but in fact I am in the foreground, and still getting that error.

Can you help me..?

Comment: The error message says that an app in background is one example because access is denied. In your case it seems to be a different reason. As your question only contains the error message but not your code that causes it is not possible to get the cause.

Comment: I have added my source code, can you help..?
Thanks